# Question about Kodibuntu auto-login default session location?

Tags: login, live-usb, lightdm

My apologies for mistakes in terminology. I only know enough to be dangerous.

OK so I'm running live USB Kodibuntu. I have a casper-rw which keeps data from session to session.

The OS automatically loads into Kodi without a "desktop" gui, as the user kodi. You can exit the app, and then you're able to login in to the "desktop" session (named either Lubuntu or Lubuntu-Netbook) to use a browser, open other apps, etc.

I've done this to install add-ons and packages, and upgrade Kodi itself (from 14 -> 16).

Now if I've logged into a session, the USB remembers that I've done this, and instead of logging me into kodi upon next reboot, it goes into the last desktop (Lubuntu or Lubuntu-Netbook). To get the USB stick to log back into Kodi, I have to logoff Lubuntu/Lubuntu-Netbook and login to Kodi.

So my question is: where is this setting kept and how can I configure it to login to "Kodi" after I've logged into a Lubuntu desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately your distribution is no official flavour of Ubuntu and off topic here. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The file is located here: ~/.dmrc